# Why my API doesn't read local JSON file? (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http, express

I'm trying to access a JSON file stored locally in my API root folder with a GET request  but it keeps waiting for the host to respond with resource and never ends, unless I request a nonexistent item.

```
    import express from 'express'
    import movies from './movies.json'

    const app = express()
    const port = process.env.PORT || '3000'

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.send('Welcome to Vidly!')
    })

    app.get('/api/movies', (req, res) => {
     res.send(movies)
    })

    app.get('/api/movies/:id', (req, res) => {
     let movie
     for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
      if(movies[i].id === parseInt(req.params.id))
       movie = movies[i]

     if (!movie) {
      return res.status(404).send(`Movie ${req.params.id} not found.`)  
     }

     return movie
   })

   app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
   })
```

Link to movies.json
http://dontpad.com/movies.json

Comment: the movies.json is an array, btw.

Comment: Which API are u talking about? `/api/movies` or `/api/movies/:id`? can u also provide the json file?

Comment: Provide your json file pls

Comment: share the movies.json file

Comment: I would recommend you to use fs (filesystem) that eases reading or writing json files

Comment: it's the /api/movies/:id

Comment: share the .json file please

Comment: provide movies.json. Also, probably better doing `res.status(200).send(movie)`. and you could use find  for movies `movies.find(movie => movie.id === parseInt(req.params.id))`

Comment: Thanks guys but the problem was much more simpler than that. Was all about writing "res.send(movie)" instead of return the value of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have three options:

A. Rename movies.json to movies.js then export the code like this

```
// movies.js
export default [
    ...
]

// index.js
import movies from './movies'
```

B. Since you're clearly using babel, you can give plugin [`inline-json-import`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-json-import) a try

C. Use file-system to clear the JSON file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const movies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/movies`, 'utf8'));
```

Comment: I'll try the first approach, but I did want to work with Json files. Since I'll need to add values to it, I'll search for the third too, with the file-system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a static file handler https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html to serve your JSON to client side.